# How can I get the vector3's names to gameobject name?

Tags: unity, c#, unityscript

```
void DrawBox()
    {
        SpawnLineGenerator(v3FrontTopLeft, v3FrontTopRight, color);
        SpawnLineGenerator(v3FrontTopRight, v3FrontBottomRight, color);
        SpawnLineGenerator(v3FrontBottomRight, v3FrontBottomLeft, color);
        SpawnLineGenerator(v3FrontBottomLeft, v3FrontTopLeft, color);

        SpawnLineGenerator(v3BackTopLeft, v3BackTopRight, color);
        SpawnLineGenerator(v3BackTopRight, v3BackBottomRight, color);
        SpawnLineGenerator(v3BackBottomRight, v3BackBottomLeft, color);
        SpawnLineGenerator(v3BackBottomLeft, v3BackTopLeft, color);

        SpawnLineGenerator(v3FrontTopLeft, v3BackTopLeft, color);
        SpawnLineGenerator(v3FrontTopRight, v3BackTopRight, color);
        SpawnLineGenerator(v3FrontBottomRight, v3BackBottomRight, color);
        SpawnLineGenerator(v3FrontBottomLeft, v3BackBottomLeft, color);
    }
```

And the gameobjects name:

```
    void SpawnLineGenerator(Vector3 start, Vector3 end, Color color)
    {
        GameObject myLine = new GameObject();
        myLine.name = start.ToString();

        myLine.transform.position = start;
        myLine.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        LineRenderer lr = myLine.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lr.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Particles/Alpha Blended Premultiply"));
        lr.startColor = color;
        lr.endColor = color;
        lr.startWidth = 0.03f;
        lr.endWidth = 0.03f;
        lr.SetPosition(0, start);
        lr.SetPosition(1, end);
    }
```

The method SpawnLineGenerator get two vector3 and a color:

```
SpawnLineGenerator(v3FrontTopLeft, v3FrontTopRight, color);
```

In the SpawnLineGenerator i'm setting a name for each gameobject:

```
 myLine.name = start.ToString();
```

This give me the name for example: (-2.1, 3.4, 4.9)
Nut I want it be the name like this format:

```
v3FrontTopLeft (-2.1, 3.4, 4.9)
v3FrontTopRight (-1.1, 3.4, 4.9)
```

The problem is if there is a easy way to get the names v3FrontTopLeft and v3FrontTopRight and the rest from the method DrawBox instead typing each one.

I want to know that (-2.1, 3.4, 4.9) are the coordinates for v3FrontTopLeft

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there is a way to [get the name of a variable in C#](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/126333/47990) (I do not recommend this), you'd still have to perform that stringification *before* calling `SpawnLineGenerator()`, at which point you may as well just do this:

```
SpawnLineGenerator(v3FrontTopLeft, v3FrontTopRight, color, "v3FrontTopLeft");
```

So no, I don't think there will be a way for you to achieve what you want the way you want to achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

As Draco18s mentioned, with your current code you'll need to get the string before calling `SpawnLineGenerator()`. If you're using C# 6, the `nameof` expression will get this name, but if the names shown are all the names needed, you can try another approach by defining an enum:

```
public enum BoxSides
{
    v3FrontTopLeft,
    v3FrontTopRight,
    ...(and so on)
}
```

Then you can change the signature to:

`void SpawnLineGenerator(BoxSides side, Vector3 start, Vector3 end, Color color)`

This will allow you to get the name you want like so:

```
myLine.name = side.ToString() + start.ToString();
```